# ifs encadeados, utilização correta

Tags: javascript

Estou criando uma função que pega os valores de uma tabela que estão em range, 1-49, 50-99, 100-199, ..., 300+, o código pega o valor de um input e baseado neste valor identifica o range e calcula o valor do produto.

Até agora o código funciona bem, pegando o valor do input, o que acontece é que quando o valor do input está em 1000 ele executa o 3º if ao invés do 5º, acredito que seja algum problema com os if encadeados, mas não consigo visualizar. Alguém me ajuda? (ps. pfv não me xinguem pq escrevi variáveis começando com letra maiúscula)

```
        var Th1 = document.getElementById('th_1').innerHTML;
        var Th2 = document.getElementById('th_2').innerHTML;
        var Th3 = document.getElementById('th_3').innerHTML;
        var Th4 = document.getElementById('th_4').innerHTML;
        var Th5 = document.getElementById('th_5').innerHTML;

        var Vl1 = Th1.slice(0, Th1.indexOf("-"));
        var Vl2 = Th1.slice(Th1.indexOf("-") + 1);

        var Vl3 = Th2.slice(0, Th2.indexOf("-"));
        var Vl4 = Th2.slice(Th2.indexOf("-") + 1);

        var Vl5 = Th3.slice(0, Th3.indexOf("-"));
        var Vl6 = Th3.slice(Th3.indexOf("-") + 1);

        var Vl7 = Th4.slice(0, Th4.indexOf("-"));
        var Vl8 = Th4.slice(Th4.indexOf("-") + 1);

        var Vl9 = Th5.slice(0, Th5.indexOf("+"));
        var Vl10 = Th5.slice(Th5.indexOf("+") + 1);


        var q = Number(document.getElementById('pwrqto').value);
        var s = document.getElementById('xprice');

        //se o valor estiver no range 1
        if((q >= Vl1) && (q <= Vl2)){
            var cat =  document.getElementById('rs_0');
            var child = cat.childNodes[0].innerHTML;
            var cleanCp = child.slice(child.indexOf(";") + 1);

            s.innerHTML = 'R$ ' + Math.ceil(cleanCp.replace(",", ".") * q) + ',00';
        }
        //se o valor estiver no range 2
        if((q >= Vl3) && (q <= Vl4)){
            var cat =  document.getElementById('rs_1');
            var child = cat.childNodes[0].innerHTML;
            var cleanCp = child.slice(child.indexOf(";") + 1);

            s.innerHTML = 'R$ ' + Math.ceil(cleanCp.replace(",", ".") * q) + ',00';
        }
        //se o valor estiver no range 3
        if((q >= Vl5) && (q <= Vl6)){
            var cat =  document.getElementById('rs_2');
            var child = cat.childNodes[0].innerHTML;
            var cleanCp = child.slice(child.indexOf(";") + 1);

            s.innerHTML = 'R$ ' + Math.ceil(cleanCp.replace(",", ".") * q) + ',00';
        }
        //se o valor estiver no range 4
        if((q >= Vl7) && (q <= Vl8)){
            var cat =  document.getElementById('rs_3');
            var child = cat.childNodes[0].innerHTML;
            var cleanCp = child.slice(child.indexOf(";") + 1);

            s.innerHTML = 'R$ ' + Math.ceil(cleanCp.replace(",", ".") * q) + ',00';
        }
        //se o valor estiver no range 5
        if(q >= Vl9) {
            var cat =  document.getElementById('rs_4');
            var child = cat.childNodes[0].innerHTML;
            var cleanCp = child.slice(child.indexOf(";") + 1);

            s.innerHTML = 'R$ ' + Math.ceil(cleanCp.replace(",", ".") * q) + ',00';
        }
```

Abaixo o Código HTML

```
<table><tbody>
  <tr class="wc_quantity">
     <th id="th_1">1-49</th>
     <th id="th_2">50-99</th>
     <th id="th_3">100-199</th>
     <th id="th_4">200-299</th>
     <th id="th_5">300+</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="wc_price">
     <td align="center" id="rs_0"><span class="amount">R$&nbsp;10,00</span></td>
     <td align="center" id="rs_1"><span class="amount">R$&nbsp;9,50</span></td>
     <td align="center" id="rs_2"><span class="amount">R$&nbsp;9,30</span></td>
     <td align="center" id="rs_3"><span class="amount">R$&nbsp;9,20</span></td>
     <td align="center" id="rs_4"><span class="amount">R$&nbsp;9,10</span></td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: Penso que um case seria mais adequado, mas como javascript não é minha praia.

Comment: Atualizei o código, para que a variável que seja um número (função Number() ), sem esta função tipo da variável era String, o que causava erros no switch condicional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso é mais adequado, mais legivel e mais rápido.

```
switch (q)
{   
     //se o valor estiver no range 1
    case ((q >= Vl1) && (q <= Vl2)):
        ...
        break;

    //se o valor estiver no range 2
    case ((q >= Vl3) && (q <= Vl4)): 
        ...
        break;
    //se o valor estiver no range 3
    case ((q >= Vl5) && (q <= Vl6)):
        ... 
        break;
    //se o valor estiver no range 4
    case ((q >= Vl7) && (q <= Vl8)):
        ...
        break;
    //se o valor estiver no range 5
    default:
        ...  
 }
```

Comment: De fato o switch resolveu o caso, eu achava que o valores do case poderiam ser apenas valores possíveis da variável (q), por isso usei vários if, Reginaldo obrigado mesmo!

Comment: Reginaldo, a resposta está correta, porém dois pontos devem ser observados:

1) como se trata de um range o default não é necessário. Pois para qualquer valor acima de VL9 aplica-se a última regra.

2) Lendo mais sobre condições no switch, deve-se utilizar (true) no lugar  de (q) pois o swith procura por um booleano.

Comment: O default é assumido quando nenhuma da condições acima satisfaz a condição. Eu assumi que a maioria dos valores estão na condição default e coloquei aqui apenas para tornar a resposta mais abrangente e didatica. Penso que o PA pode alterar e colocar nessa posição a condição que mais ocorre ou se não for o caso substitui-lo de vez por um outro case normal.

Comment: @ReginaldoRigo de qualquer forma o Douglas esta correto quanto ao `q` em `switch (q)` ter que ser um valor `booleano`, veja: https://jsfiddle.net/wmvmuacz/

Comment: Douglas. Veja esse exemplos: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_switch.asp